# Como hago para guardar un video de el resultado de un programa de una IA con python?

Tags: python, inteligencia-artificial

Quiero que al terminar el programa de la IA, se guarden los resultados en forma de vídeo.

Instalé `ffmpeg` y lo uso así:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    environment=gym.make("MountainCar-v0")
    agent = QLearner(environment)
    learned_policy=train(agent, environment)
    monitor_path="./monitor_output"
    environment=gym.wrappers.Monitor(environment, monitor_path, force = True)
    for _ in range(1000):
        test(agent, environment, learned_policy)
    environment.close();
```

Pero el video me sale corrupto.
¿Saben cómo solucionar esto? ¿U otro programa de renderizado de vídeo que me sirva para esto?